# Multiple field searches in MVC 3 using C #

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am relatively new to MVC 3. i was just wondering if there is a way to do multiple field searches.

I'm looking to have many textboxes on a page, where the user can input search criteria such as Region, Salesperson Rating, Salesperson Subject, etc .
and then when the user clicks the search button it should populate a list with Salespeople matching the criteria entered.

I have been looking on the web and i haven't found a concrete answer...

Thank you in advance...

Comment: what has mvc got to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a grid like [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) to get these kinds of functionalities. It's relatively easy to implement in asp.net mvc. I once wrote a [mvc helper](http://www.webpirates.nl/webpirates/robin-van-der-knaap/47-fluent-jqgrid-html-helper-for-aspnet-mvc) for jqgrid, it's built for mvc2 but can also be used in mvc3 as well. There's also a sample app for the helper, you can find it [here](http://www.playground.webpirates.nl/MvcJqGrid/Home/Search) to see if fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple parameters passed to a controller action, e.g. by defining a form with multiple input fields in your view and let the form post to the action url. The data can be passed using multiple method parameters, a custom model class that defines the relevant properties, or simply by using a form collection.